# Парсер скидывает на 404 ошибку

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Доброго времени суток всем, собственно по быстрому написал маленький парсер используя **Simple HTML DOM**, собственно все работает как мне необходимо кроме одной вещи, я получаю ссылки на товары со страницы категории, пишу их в массив и далее пытаюсь спарсить каждую страницу, но не тут то было, меня (парсер) почему то скидывает на 404 страницу, если же написать ссылку вручную, а не забирать с массива, то все работает должным образом. Может кто сталкивался, что сможете посоветовать? Код прилагаю ниже.

```
<?php 
$url=$_GET['url'];
$site_url = 'https://koleso2000.ua';
$category_url = 'https://koleso2000.ua/shini';

if(isset($url) && $url != "")
    {
        require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

        for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $category_url.'?page='.$i.'');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $result_category = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);        

                $html_category = str_get_html($result_category);

                if(count($html_category->find("/html",0)))
                    {                               
                        foreach($html_category->find('div.productsWrap a') as $href)
                            {
                                if($href->plaintext != 'Купить ')
                                    {
                                        if($href->href != $duble)
                                        {
                                            $product_url[] = $site_url.$href->href.'</br>';
                                            $duble = $href->href;                                   
                                        }
                                    }

                            }   
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo 'Не загружен объект категории!';
                    }
            }   


        foreach($product_url as $url_product)
            {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url_product );
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $html = str_get_html($result);

                if(count($html->find("/html",0)))
                    {       
                        $price  = $html->find('span.price',0);          
                        $price = $price->plaintext; 
                        $price = str_replace(" грн ", "", $price);
                        $price = strip_tags($price);        

                        $image = $html->find('img',2);
                        $image_src = $image->src; 
                        $image_alt = $image->alt;
                        $image =  '<a href="https://koleso2000.ua/'.$image_src.'">'.$image_alt.'</a></br>';     

                        $name = $html->find('h1',0);;
                        $name = $name->innertext;
                        $name = strip_tags($name);

                        $brand  = $html->find('div.second p a',1);          
                        $brand = $brand->plaintext; 
                        $brand = strip_tags($brand);

                        $model = $html->find('div.in-top p',0);
                        $model = strip_tags($model);
                        $model = str_replace(" ", "", $model);
                        $model = explode(':',$model);
                        $model = $model[1];

                        $width = $html->find('div.second p',2);
                        $width = $width->plaintext; 
                        $width = strip_tags($width);

                        $height = $html->find('div.second p',3);
                        $height = $height->plaintext; 
                        $height = strip_tags($height);

                        $diameter = $html->find('div.second p',4);
                        $diameter = $diameter->plaintext; 
                        $diameter = strip_tags($diameter); 

                        $speed = $html->find('div.second p',5);
                        $speed = $speed->plaintext; 
                        $speed = strip_tags($speed);

                        $weight = $html->find('div.second p',6);
                        $weight = $weight->plaintext; 
                        $weight = strip_tags($weight);

                        $season = $html->find('div.second p',7);
                        $season = $season->plaintext; 
                        $season = strip_tags($season);

                        $ship = $html->find('div.second p',8);
                        $ship = $ship->plaintext; 
                        $ship = strip_tags($ship);

                        $type = $html->find('div.second p',9);
                        $type = $type->plaintext; 
                        $type = strip_tags($type);

                        echo '<img src="https://koleso2000.ua/'.$image_src.'" alt="'.$image_alt.'" style = "width:200px;"><br><br>';                
                        echo 'Наименование - '.$name.'<br>';
                        echo 'Цена - '.$price.'<br>';
                        echo 'Картинка - '.$image.'';
                        echo 'Бренд - '.$brand.'<br>';  
                        echo 'Код - '.$model.'<br>';
                        echo 'Ширина - '.$width.'<br>';
                        echo 'Высота - '.$height.'<br>';
                        echo 'Диаметр - '.$diameter.'<br>';
                        echo 'Индекс скорости - '.$speed.'<br>';        
                        echo 'Индекс нагрузки - '.$weight.'<br>';
                        echo 'Сезон - '.$season.'<br>';
                        echo 'Шипы - '.$ship.'<br>';
                        echo 'Тип - '.$type.'<br><br>';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo "Объект не загружен!";
                    }

                $html->clear();
                unset($html);
            }   
    }
else
    {
        echo 'Не передана ссылка на страницу';
    }

?>
```

Comment: вы в консоль выведите URL по которой парсер забирает страницу, и откройте в браузере

Comment: @teran пробовал уже =) По выведенной ссылке все нормально открывается в браузере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо проблему решил самостоятельно, всему виной была моя конкатенация в создании массива ссылок на товары, для теста изначально выводил с переносом на следующую строку, а после переделки забыл убрать **.'< /br>'** собственно из за этого парсер и отправляли на **404.**